# Determine whether these structures are is isomorphic

Tags: logic, model-theory

Determine whether these structures are is isomorphic ? ,

if they are isomorphic Show the isomorphism function and proved

if they are no isomorphic proved by an appropriate verse

A. $M_2= \langle(1,\infty),+\rangle$ ,  $M_1 =  \langle(0,\infty),+\rangle$

***attempt:***

if i want to show isomphism in A. or B.  i need to show .

for all sign of function $f$

1.$h(F^{M}(a_1,a_2,...a_n))=F^N(h(a_1),h(a_2),...(h(a_n))$

2.Injective function

3.Surjective function

if i try to prove isomorphic in B. between $M_2$ , $M_1$
i dont know how to prove them with in open segment

Comment: Please move point B in another question as you edited it in a way that answers have to be thought again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question A**

The sentence $\phi \equiv \forall x \exists y(y+y=x)$ is satisfied in $M_1$ but not $M_2$. Therefore the two structures can't be isomorphic.

Comment: $0\not\in(0,+\infty)$

Comment: @StinkingBishop That is a good comment... Thanks!

Comment: sorry some 1 edit my post its cannot be + in question B its a $\cdot$ in $M_1$ and $M_2$ ..

Comment: @Emily.d You were the one editing the post. Then I suggest that you take only point A in this question and open a new question for point B. Answering to moving question is really not pleasant!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net i swear i didnt notice about that . i am really sorry !!..

about question A you can please explain why $\phi \equiv \forall x \exists y(y+y=x)$ ?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net in this $ \forall x \exists y(y+y=x)$ in option A its see its isomphism

Comment: It is impossible to find an isomorphism for case A. An isomorphism preserves validity of sentences and $\phi$ is satisfied in $M_1$ and not in $M_2$. And again please move question B in another question as you edited it.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net please you can explain the preserves validity of sentences ? 
and how its impossible that $\phi \equiv $ satisfied  $M_1$ and not in $M_2$ because $M_1$ are numbers in range ( .. ) and   $M_2$ ( .. ) so how the $\phi$ come to take a role .

Comment: I imagine that you're following (or reading) an introductory course in logic / model theory. You should refer to it as what I use is explained there. The $\phi$ I used is just saying *for all element $x$  it exists an element that is half of $x$*. This is true in $M_1$ but not in $M_2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117183/discussion-between-emily-d-and-mathcounterexamples-net).